# Matlab : Export netcdf timestamped variable

Tags: matlab, variables, timestamp, element, netcdf

I'm saving a 1x50 array in a variable in a netCDF file and this operation is done every ~10sec.
I would like also to save matlab'time datestr(now) (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS).

How should I do ?
I tried to store the date (datestr(now)) in a time variable without success.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

To store a variable in your workspace to a .mat file, you can use this:

```
variable = 1; % Variable to store.
fileName = ['fileName - ', datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH.MM.SS'), '.mat'];
save(fileName, '-mat', 'variable');
```

Note that a ':' in the date string will make the `save()` function throw an error.

Comment: @CUEIRB22 Did this help? If it did help, you should mark the answer as accepted. Otherwise, please give more information on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly succeed in store time in my netCDF file.
1. I defined a 'time' dimension
2. I defined a dimension for my 1x50 value
then I wrote my data

```
ncwrite(ncfilename, 'data',myData.',[1 i]);
ncwrite(ncfilename, 'time',myData_triggertime,i);
```

where myData (my 1x50 array), myData_triggertime (=datestr(now)) are updated at each acquisition loop and i incremented at each loop.

kind regards